# Mesh Collider has walls where holes should be and is deformed

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I need a curve cylinder collider for my curve water pipe model so that my player red cube can pass easily through.

I tried mesh collider it doesn't works and also tried another trick where I build 2 models in blender one for mesh render, one for collider. one as a whole one in 9 chunks cause mesh collider was not working on whole one object check pic no:1 and check pic no:5 where after exporting both models to unity I applied mesh collider on all 9 chunks of pipe separately to get perfect results in pic no:5 results of collider look's perfect but not working perfect the red box Player can't pass through the pipe

Collider doesn't let the player get inside and out from another side as shown in pictures. I need a perfect collider for my curve pipe so that my player can easily pass through. In pic one I showed that after applying mesh collider results. In pic two I showed I build my model again but in 9 chunks as one chunk is selected you can see, To apply mesh collider on all 9 chunks separately to get good results. In pic 5 I showed final result it looks good but not working the collider is not letting my small red box player inside the pipe and pass through it. In pic 3 I am aiming. In pic 4 I fire and showed that our player does'nt get in the pipe.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused because Unity is turning your Mesh into a **convex** shape, which removes holes from the tube. It will also reduces the vertex count down to 255 triangles, the maximum for a convex mesh. That is why the collider gets so deformed in the first picture.

There are 2 main options for you here, because tubes are inherently non-convex shapes.

1. Make sure `Convex` is **not checked** on the mesh collider and that there is **no rigidbody** on the tube. Then, the cubes should be able to enter the tube. However, this will mean that **other MeshColliders will not be able to collide with the tube**. If you're only colliding it with BoxColliders, SphereColliders, or CapsuleColliders and so on, this should work fine.
2. Break up the tubes into a series of **convex** shapes, and make each one a **separate** MeshCollider. Then the situation you have here should work fine.

From the documentation of MeshCollider:

> **Convex** - Tick the checkbox to enable Convex. If enabled, this Mesh Collider collides with other Mesh Colliders. **Convex Mesh Colliders are limited to 255 triangles. **

...

> Mesh Colliders that do not have **Convex** enabled are only supported on GameObjects without a **Rigidbody**
>   component.

Comment: Perfect Now I got another problem I uncheck the convex now its working but only from out side not inside means when I put our player inside the tube and play the scene the player does'nt collide with tube it does'nt stay's inside the tube it falls down but when I put it on the top of tube play scene it collides Then I get back to blender I made 2 tubes one for collider one for mesh render. I flipped the normals of colliders one and let the mesh render tube as same export to unity and apply the same as u taught me it work perfectly so fliping normals and un checking convex was the key. Thanks.

Comment: @BakhtyarKhan I'm glad I could help :) Don't forget to upvote or mark this answer as the accepted answer by clicking on the grey checkmark. It helps other people with a similar problem as yours find the answer and also gives me some reputation points ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: :) I m new in stackoverflow.

Comment: I posted another question can u answer please my new question need someone really experienced. :)