# Unity3D : Collision detection problem on custom assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a maze game where the user finds the way to the door (or something). I have designed the maze in blender. Inside Unity, I imported the maze as custom asset. The cube which is the player in my game goes through the walls. I have added `RigidBody` to the player  so that I can move the player using `rigidBody.AddForce()` method in C#. I have also added `Box Collider` to the player. **How do I prevent moving through parts of custom assets (Walls in my situation)?**

Comment: Did you add box colliders to all the different walls of the custom asset in unity?

Comment: Well, I have thought of those. But adding Box Colliders to all the walls would  consume a lot of time.

Comment: Use a mesh collider and then this will be a duplicate of your situation: [Tube Mesh Collider has walls in holes and is deformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279930/hole-in-tube-collider-is-solid-wall)